# How to get the last 3 items from an xml file with simpleXml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

A bit of a noob when it come s to php and xml but how to get the latest 3 items from a xml file?

```
$xmlstr= '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<tran>
<balance>25000</balance>
<amount>560</amount>
</tran>

<tran>
<amount>5999</amount>
<balance>30999</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
<amount>5000</amount>
<balance>20000</balance>
</tran>
<tran>
<amount>8923</amount>
<balance>25000</balance>
</tran>
...
...
</doc>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use XPath with SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). The following XPath should return the last 3 `tran` elements from the XML :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$result = $xml->xpath("//tran[position() > last()-3]");
```

Comment: `//tran[position() >= last()-2]` returns the last 3 `tran` elements

Comment: My bad, I meant `last()-3` instead of `last()-2`. I was testing using smaller number of elements..